# Jackson @JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS) for all children

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a complex multi-tier inheritance/enclosure class structure in my legacy application (going more than 3 levels deep for most classes).

Now, we want to stream these to the front end as a JSON using Jackson.

Our (legacy) front end client bombs out when certain fields are missing all together. So, instead we'd have to send `property=null` as part of JSON.

I'm familiar with `@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)` (see for example, https://wilddiary.com/jackson-ignore-null-and-empty-fields/) and that works great for individual classes.

The problem is that I'd need to include this annotation individually for each of the small child classes, which is tedious.

The question is: is it possible somehow set this (or any other) flag on the main parent class so that it propagates to all its children?

Comment: I also have the same problem. Using `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);` is not showing the null values. Anyone have found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can just register this in your ObjectMapper:

`mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);`

Answer (score -1):

JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)

---

Value that indicates that property is to be always included, independent of value of the property.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question and adds nothing to the explanation on JsonInclude that was already done in the question